# How can I use code from a Github gist in my Codepen (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, github, src, gist

I've got [a gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Rusty25/3f08edf4e64d3373511df9a8a4ef45f4/raw/3309040df917ef771807dd00b849c47b3dad01c4/gistfile1.js) that has the following code:

```
var hello = "Hello World!"
```

I'd like to be able to use it in my Codepen project's Javascript, but I'm not sure how. I tried using Github's embed feature, but that just displays a link to the gist and nothing more.

Here's the link to my Codepen:

```
http://codepen.io/Random_Pseudonym/pen/EWvdge
```

Answer (score 1):

The protocol in the gist that you've shown uses
    `https//gist.github.com/Rusty25/3f08edf4e64d3373511df9a8a4ef45f4.js`

Should it not be
    `https://gist.github.com/Rusty25/3f08edf4e64d3373511df9a8a4ef45f4.js`?